# Missing field in Android library

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-proguard

I'm currently using an external library (from a url specified in gradle) that relies on OKHttp and Retrofit.

It appears to break when working with another library, but my app only installs and runs when minifyEnabled is set to true, and a long proguard file is specified.

**Problem:** One of the fields in the first library is said to be missing, which Gson/Retrofit needs and throws an `Assertion missing field` error when trying to use a method from said library in my onCreate() method.

Proguard file:

```
# Add any project specific keep options here:
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable#, !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, EnclosingMethod, InnerClasses, Exceptions, Signature#, LocalVariableTable, LocalVariableTypeTable
#-keep,allowshrinking,allowoptimization class * { <methods>; }

# This will break the installation step if minify is enabled.
#-dontobfuscate

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keep class Voice { Voice.DownloadStatus mDownloadStatus;}

# Retrofit
-dontwarn com.facebook.android.BuildConfig

-dontwarn rx.**

-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*

-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class retrofit.** { *; }

-dontwarn java.util.zip.*

-dontnote java.util.zip.*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

#-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
```

My best guess is Proguard is making a mess out of duplicate/shuffled classes.

Here's the app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.redacted.redacted"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
   compile files('libs/pcr.jar')
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
   compile 'com.pebblebee:pb-android-lib-bluetooth:2.0.411'
   compile 'com.euphonyinc:euphonium-library:0.21'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?